# Is there a word for a person who has lost their sibling?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word that applies to a person who has lost their sibling, such as widow/widower for a married person who has lost their partner?

Comment: Although I voted to close this question as a duplicate of the one that Kristina Lopez links to, it seems to me that if the question here were altered to refer specifically to a person with multiple  siblings who loses one but not all of them (to death), the case might be different enough to justify reopening this question.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's necessary to reword the question. It doesn't presuppose a single sibling who has died, and no others. However, one of the answers at the duplicate is *bereaved sibling,* which **does** answer this question. So if there are any other answers, they would be better added to the other question.